# Change degrees of freedom for Statsmodel

Tags: python, regression, stata, statsmodels

I recently switched from Stata to Python, using `statsmodel` for my regressions.

I discovered that `statsmodel` is very slow for many fixed-effect (e.g. city dummies). In Stata I would use the `areg` command for such a task, which essentially demeans all variables by the fixed-effect dummies (https://www.stata.com/manuals14/rareg.pdf).

I managed to write a python function to do the same with my pandas data frame before feeding it into the `statsmodel`

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
smf.ols().fit()
```

The problem is that Stata adjusts the degrees of freedom for the absorbed dummies which I somehow cannot get to work.

Is there a way to tell `statsmodel` the residual degrees of freedom?
Alternatively, is there a similar option in `statsmodel` like `areg` for large groups of fixed-effects?

Comment: https://www.stata.com/manuals/rareg.pdf is always the latest version of the documentation, although I doubt that is material to the question.

Comment: It's not in statsmodels, but linearmodels has a version https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/absorbing/linearmodels.iv.absorbing.AbsorbingLS.html